# richtextbox is eatting Chinese pinyin IME box?

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

so I have a RichTextBox and I would like to type Chinese into it. I tried various Pinyin input methods including Microsoft Pinyin and Google Pinyin. it's working fine. but as soon as I have the following defined in the Keydown Event, it stopped working:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 1) //<--- this is causing the issue??
    {

    }
}
```

take google Pinyin as example. it only take the first character, for example if I want to type "wo" as soon as I type "o" the pop up candidate box would disappear. the MS Pinyin is even worse... 

this is totally annoying, I don't understand why the candidate box got eaten by merely having this "if" check. it looks to me like a RichTextBox control bug?

any suggestions comments anyone?

thanks!

Comment: What is the code inside this if condition?

Comment: surprisingly nothing.... I just have this "if" with empty code inside and it can be easily reproduced.